# Calling SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(); stops server function from runing via google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi there and thanks in advance!

I created a sidepanel in an Google Spreadsheet with a button. Clicking the button will run a server function. This functions shows an alertbox and inserts text into a specific cell.

Working Example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mv-0YRSJJpwSaRh_xAeZDtVqL-P-e5nS80fUJIq_CJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Now comes the tricky part:
I am using this code in an other sheet which i cant share because it contains confidential data. And in this sheet the function only runs when I delete or //deactivate the line with the alert() call.

I know its a bit hard to find errors like that, but maybe someone has an idea what it could be?

CODE.GS

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('myToDoPanelLabel', 'showTestPanel')
      .addToUi();
}

function insert(value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Message"); //with this line it only works in test sheet but not in the original sheet
  var thisID="1Mv-0YRSJJpwSaRh_xAeZDtVqL-P-e5nS80fUJIq_CJ4";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisID).getSheetByName("Tab1");
  ss.getRange(1,2).setValue("New Txt");

}


function showTestPanel() {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('panel');
  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
  .setTitle('ToDoPanel');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput); 
}
```

---

PANEL.HTML

```
<script>
  window.mark = function() {
   google.script.run.insert();
  };
</script>

<button onclick='mark()'>click me</button>
```

Edit: The core of the problem is that no dialogue box is showing up! With the alert() call it will stop the code(the timeout can be seen in the Scrip Logging "Timeout while waiting on user response"). With the solution suggested bellow it will execute but still not show up the custom dialogue.
Is this some permission issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, [`.alert`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt) blocks the server execution. Quoting:

> Opens a dialog box in the user's editor with the given message and an "OK" button. This method suspends the server-side script while the dialog is open. The script resumes after the user dismisses the dialog, but Jdbc connections and LockService locks don't persist across the suspension.

As they suggest in [their Dialog guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs), you could use a Custom dialog:

> Custom dialogs **do not** suspend the server-side script while the dialog is open. The client-side component can make asynchronous calls to the server-side script using either the google.script API for HTML-service interfaces or server handlers for UI-service interfaces.

So, creating a custom dialog might solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Adelin for the hint! It doesnt solve the whole issue, but part of it, and takes me closer to the problem. 
Trying out your suggestion, the custom dialog didnt show up, but the rest of the function got executed.
So I suspect it has something to do with the permission to show dialogue box and I havent found out how to grant them because you cant invoke dialogue box from the editor...